# I want to close this as "too broad"

Tags: discussion

I want to VTC as "too broad" but remember Zanna's great advice a week or fortnight ago to bring issues up here when in doubt.

Here is the question: [My average laptop temperature is 75C. Is it Normal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254073/my-average-laptop-temperature-is-75c-is-it-normal)

The reason is another answer was just posted today and it is yet another example of many different answers.

To VTC or not to VTC that is the question.

Comment: But why bother with old questions? Especially ones that are upvoted and answered. Unless it's harmful and should be removed from existence, I don't see any reason why to include another question to the big queue of close votes. IMO, it's just a waste of reviewers' time. I'd say, it's better to edit and salvage the question and its answers when that's possible.

Comment: Why bother? An answer which was just listed brought this to my attention. A right or wrong answer depends on a specific laptop model and sometimes OS Version. I could post three different answers based on my laptops. So the answers can grow to hundreds. Many of them wrong for the OP but probably right for the answerer.

Comment: Upon reviewing the question, IMHO it's far from too broad as the system model number and specifications are included in the question. I concur with karel on this.

Comment: @ElderGeek My last comment was quickly done on my cell phone. I **wish** I had reread the question. As it turns out the new answer that made me wonder if the question was too broad has been deleted. Now all that remains are old answers to an old question so I'll side with you, Dan and Karel. Especially as Dan points out the review queues are backed up. "Is 75 degrees normal?" in the title remains subjective as it depends on what you are doing.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I can't imagine trying to vet this stuff on my cell phone. The screen is too small for my old eyes. I  only skimmed the answers to be honest. My opinion is strictly hardware based. depending on the hardware 75C might just be fatal to some components. For instance https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#performanceOperatingTemperature

Comment: @ElderGeek I hate to say it but I don't even use my reading glasses with my cell phone. Even though the resolution is 1920x1080 it's only a six inch screen. By comparison my laptop screen is same resolution at 17.4" and TV is same resolution at 50". You can actually see what you are reading instead of guessing :) As far as 75C goes it was typical for my older Toshiba Celeron Duo T5750 and and older Dell IvyBridge 3630QM but the new Alienware Skylake 6700HQ is currently running at 48C. I would prefer question asked "How can I make my laptop run cooler" rather than "Is 75C normal?".

Comment: @ElderGeek Twitter style part 2: The critical levels (read shutdown) is 100C-105C and Powerclamp kicks in around 86C (if you remember to install it). Once again only the old Toshiba and old Dell got hot (had to replace fans, compressed air, etc.). But the new Skylake the fan doesn't even come on. Actually it has two fans that don't come on unless it's gaming in Windows.

Comment: *Why bother with old questions?* Because [we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/tour) Because every person I talk to about AU tells me they nearly always find the answer before they need to ask. The only thing special about new questions is that the OP probably needs help, but *SE questions are not primarily for their askers*.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Clearly there's enough information in the question that it doesn't qualify as too broad. Too localized *perhaps* but not too broad. Cheers! I'm off to troubleshoot a Windows installation. (I get paid for that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has an interesting accepted answer and some other useful answers that were upvoted a few times. Based on the potential usefulness of its answers I would vote to leave the question open if I was reviewing it. My potential usefulness standard by which something may be judged or decided is that there is something for anyone who has a similar problem in the answers to the question.

Comment: I could post three different answers for three different laptops in my line of sight. Which is why I felt it was too broad. Everyone and their dog could have a different answer based on their experiences with only  one laptop.

Comment: Your comment was thought provoking. My "potential usefulness" standard by which something may be judged or decided is that there is something for anyone who has a similar problem in the question.

Comment: 75C is such a border-line number. 40s great. 80s bad. 90s hide the kids. I prefer questions like, How do I reduce the temp. Why is my fan always off. Why is my fan full blast. etc.

Comment: This was always a borderline decision for me and a discussion issue. If I knew for sure I would have VTC'd without coming in here. I thank yourself, Elder Geek and Dan for all your time and input. Democracy in action: +1 and accept.

Comment: Thanks for commenting and I [linked your question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12976/reopen-request-for-installing-fltk-on-virtualbox/12977#comment35940_12977) to an answer to a Meta question that I asked at Superuser which was answered by Journeyman Geek. Judging by the comments I've received I'm faring rather badly with my question there so far.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I was linked :) I had to put in a little clarification on the link... I didn't VTC as too broad I was asking if people thought it *should* be. The consensus is it shouldn't be. I'm actually very happy to learn that and the underlying reasons.